# Spring boot 3 and JPA with H2: Could not commit JPA transaction

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, h2, lombok

I'm working with Spring Boot 3, Java 21 restful API and JPA with H2 and I've got a problem with handling transactions.

I have 3 controllers (Users, Roles, Addresses) working with the basic CRUD (get, post and delete).

For the `Colony` Controller I having a problem with the post method to create a new Colony. The error message is:

> Failed to save colony with reason: Could not commit JPA transaction

See below for details for Colony.

ColonyController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/colonies")
public class ColonyController {
    ColonyService colonyService;

    public ColonyController(ColonyService colonyService) {
        this.colonyService = colonyService;
    }

    @PostMapping("")
    public Colony createColony(@RequestBody Colony colony) {
        return colonyService.createColony(colony);        
    }
}
```

Colony Service:

```
public interface ColonyService {     
    public List<Colony> findAll();     
    public Colony createColony(Colony colony);     
    public Colony deleteById(String id);     
    public Colony findById(UUID id); 
}
```

Colony Service Implementation

```
@Component
public class ColonyServiceImpl implements ColonyService{
    ColonyRepository colonyRepository;

    public ColonyServiceImpl(ColonyRepository colonyRepository) {
        this.colonyRepository = colonyRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Colony createColony(Colony colony) {
        Colony newColony = null;
        try {
            colony.setAddresses(Collections.emptySet());
            newColony = colonyRepository.save(colony);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ColonyRepositoryException("Failed to save colony with reason: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return newColony;
    }
   
}
```

Colony model:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Colony extends Audit{
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @UuidGenerator
    private UUID id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "colony")
    private Set<Address> addresses;

    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    @NotEmpty
    private boolean active = true;

    @PrePersist
    public void setCreatedAt() {
        this.setCreatedAt(LocalDateTime.now());
    }
}
```

Address model:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Address extends Audit {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @UuidGenerator
    private UUID id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "address", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JsonIgnore
    private Colony colony;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 3, max = 55)
    private String line1;

    private String line2;

    private String line3;

    @NotEmpty
    private String postalCode;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 2,max = 2)
    private String country; // (always required, 2 character ISO code)

    @NotEmpty
    private String state; // (ISO code when available)

    @NotEmpty
    private String city;  // (City)

    private String locality;  //(Neighborhood / Suburb)
    
    private String premise; // house / apt / building

    @NotNull
    private boolean active = true;


    @PrePersist
    public void setCreatedAt() {
        this.setCreatedAt(LocalDateTime.now());
    }
}
```

Colony Repository:

```
public interface ColonyRepository extends JpaRepository<Colony, UUID> {
}
```

My postman request is the following

[postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqbv6.png)

The only header I have for the request is:

`Accept: application/json`

The JSON response and stack trace are the following:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2024-01-02T00:27:36.124+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "trace": "com.toshi.rest.residencial.exceptions.ColonyRepositoryException: Failed to save colony with reason: Could not commit JPA transaction\n\tat com.toshi.rest.residencial.services.ColonyServiceImpl.createColony(ColonyServiceImpl.java:36)\n\tat com.toshi.rest.residencial.controllers.ColonyController.createColony(ColonyController.java:63)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:262)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:917)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:829)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914)\n\tat jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)\n\tat jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)\n",
    "message": "Failed to save colony with reason: Could not commit JPA transaction",
    "path": "/colonies"
}
```

What I'd expect to happen: New entry added to the H2 colony table.

What happens: 500 response with error message:`Could not commit JPA transaction`

Any help or insight will be much appreciated!

Stack trace:

```
com.toshi.rest.residencial.exceptions.ColonyRepositoryException: Failed to save colony with reason: Could not commit JPA transaction
    at com.toshi.rest.residencial.services.ColonyServiceImpl.createColony(ColonyServiceImpl.java:36)
    at com.toshi.rest.residencial.controllers.ColonyController.createColony(ColonyController.java:63)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:262)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:917)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:829)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
```

Comment: Can you please show the full stack trace?

Comment: @dan1stiscrying I updated the post with the stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error "Could not commit JPA transaction" typically indicates an issue during the commit phase of a transaction in your Spring Data JPA application. Can you take a look on below points:
Database Constraint Violation:
Check your Colony entity for constraints (e.g., @NotEmpty, @Size, etc.). Make sure the data you are trying to save adheres to these constraints. If there is a constraint violation, it can lead to a transaction failure.
Check on you inputs.

```
Nested Transactions:
    If you are using nested transactions, especially if you have multiple @Transactional methods being called within one another, ensure that you are handling transactions correctly. Nested transactions might not be supported or behave as expected in all scenarios.
check on call your making

Optimistic Locking:
    If you have fields annotated with @Version for optimistic locking in your entities, ensure that these fields are being updated correctly. Optimistic locking can cause transaction failures if the version doesn't match during an update.

Database Connection Issues:
    Check your H2 database connection. Ensure that the database is running and that your application can connect to it. Look for any additional error messages in the logs related to database connection issues.

Transaction Timeout:
    Check if there is a transaction timeout configured, and if the operation takes too long, it might result in a transaction failure. You can adjust the transaction timeout if needed.

Transactional Method Placement:
    Ensure that the @Transactional annotation is applied to the correct method. It should be on the method that initiates the transaction. In your case, it seems like createColony should be annotated with @Transactional.

Logging:
    Add more logging statements in your code to trace the flow of execution. This can help you identify the point where the transaction fails.
```

Here is a revised version of your ColonyServiceImpl with additional logging:

```
@Component
public class ColonyServiceImpl implements ColonyService {

    private final ColonyRepository colonyRepository;

    public ColonyServiceImpl(ColonyRepository colonyRepository) {
        this.colonyRepository = colonyRepository;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Colony createColony(Colony colony) {
        try {
            colony.setAddresses(Collections.emptySet());
            Colony newColony = colonyRepository.save(colony);
            return newColony;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Log the exception for debugging purposes
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new ColonyRepositoryException("Failed to save colony with reason: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

In this version, I added the @Transactional annotation to the createColony method. Also, I added a log statement using e.printStackTrace() to print the stack trace of the exception. This can help you identify the root cause of the issue.

Please review the points mentioned above, and based on the logs and additional information, you might be able to pinpoint the issue causing the transaction failure.

Comment: Thanks @Deepak for the insights. The lines `@Transactional` and `e.printStackTrace();` help me identify the root cause of the exception which was:
`UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty' validating type 'java.lang.Boolean'. Check configuration for 'active'`

Answer (score 1):

The @Transactional annotation in Spring (including Spring Boot) is used to define the scope of a single database transaction. It can be applied at the method level or at the class level.

**When to use @Transactional:**

1. Database Operations: When you have multiple database operations that
   need to be treated as a single unit of work. For instance, consider
   a scenario where you need to save or update multiple entities within
   a single transaction.
2. Prevent Inconsistent State: To ensure data consistency, especially
   when multiple operations need to succeed or fail together. The
   @Transactional annotation helps to roll back all changes if any
   operation fails within the transaction, preventing inconsistent
   states in the database.
3. Default Transaction Configuration: When applied at the class level,
   @Transactional on a service class indicates that all public methods
   in that class are transactional. However, method-level annotations.

In your code, You're tryin gto perform the operation in the DB, so it requires you to use the **@Transactional** annotation at the service layer(where you trying to save it using Repository Instance).

```
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Colony createColony(Colony colony) {...}
```

Please accept the answer if it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).